# Where are procedures stored in epicor

Tags: progress-4gl, epicorerp

1) Where are procedures for ABL code stored in epicor?

2) What are these type of syntax mean:

```
{manager/Exception.i &TO_LOG}
{bo/BOName_ds.i}
```

are they reference to a lib or a physical file? If it is a file, where do they reside?

Comment: I'm not sure what Epicor is, but those two lines are include files. They are physical files. Go to your start-in folder and look for "manager" and "bo" subfolders. The files should be in there.

Comment: These are "include files" that tell the compiler to go fetch this file and include it in your source code before compiling it. In the first case the Exception.i file will be "xcoded" which means the compiler can read and use the file, but you will only see its encrypted form. This is how Epicor protects some of it proprietary content.

Answer (score 1):

```
{manager/Exception.i &TO_LOG}
```

Somewhere one your file (in your so-called `PROPATH` - the directories that Progress uses to run itself and your application) is a directory named `manager`. Within that directory is a file named `Exception.i`.

When Exception.i is included  some argument is passed along to it (&TO_LOG). See more below about the arguments.

{bo/BOName_ds.i}

As above but a directory called `bo` and a file named `BOName_ds.i`. This might be a "business object" (because of the BO-part) that's defined as a "dataset" - the ds-part, but it could also be something specific to your application.

**Include file arguments**

Here's two examples of passing unnamed and named arguments to an include file.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iVar AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO INIT 3.

{includefile1.i 1 iVar TRUE}

{includefile2.i &EXAMPLE="'hello'" &VIEWAS="VIEW AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION"}
```

The first include file:
    /* includefile1.i */
    MESSAGE {1} {2} {3} VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

The second include file:
    MESSAGE {&EXAMPLE} {&VIEWAS}.

Result from the first include:

[image]

Result from the second include:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jensd. I see that the .I files are binary. What editor do I use to edit source? what is the extension for the source files? Sorry for such a beginner question.

Comment: I are usually includes in text format. If they are compiled ita a problem since theres no built in or free decompiler (that i know of). Sometimes there are .pl files (like archives). Perhaps look for those?